# osmdroid LoggerFactory error, after re-opening app

Tags: android, osmdroid

In my osmdroid project, the error below is what used to happen when I was missing the library `slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

I added that library, and the app runs perfect the first time.  But when I close the app and re-open it, I again get the error on start-up.

I have to reinstall the app every time I want the app to open successfully.

Edit:  I now have the android specific version of slf4j, but that does not seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the **Android specific** version of sl4fj. I use slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar with no problems. There is a later candidate for release. Both jars may be downloaded from [this page](http://www.slf4j.org/android/)

Comment: I was hoping that what the issue, but unfortunately it still occurs.